# When do we have $A/\mathfrak{m}\cong A_{\mathfrak{m}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian commutative ring. Suppose that there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$ such that there exists an isomorphism $A/\mathfrak{m}\cong A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ of rings where $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{m}$. **Is it true that $\mathfrak{m}$ is the zero ideal? If not, can additional conditions be added to make it true?**

Comment: can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 2):

It does not follow that $\mathfrak m$ is the zero ideal. For example, consider the ring $K \times L$, where $K$ and $L$ are fields and $\mathfrak m = K \times 0$. Both $A_{\mathfrak m}$ and $A / \mathfrak m$ are isomorphic to $L$.

In order to get the statement $\mathfrak m = 0$, you need additional information. I expect that $A$ having no nontrivial idempotents and the isomorphism $A / \mathfrak m \cong A_{\mathfrak m}$ being a map of *$A$-algebras* instead of just rings should suffice. I'm still thinking about the argument, though.

Comment: I don't see the isomorphism $A_\mathfrak{m}\simeq L$ so clearly. Can you ecplain how you prove it ?

Comment: We have $(1, 0) \cdot (0, 1) = 0$ in $A$. Since $(0, 1)$ is not an element of $\mathfrak m$, it goes to a unit in $A_{\mathfrak m}$. Therefore, $(1, 0)$ is zero in the localisation. This is also true for the ideal generated by $(1, 0)$, which is $\mathfrak m$. Thus, $A \to A_{\mathfrak m}$ factors through $A / \mathfrak m = L$. This is already a field, so there is nothing further to localise.